# LD_PRELOAD not preloading all symbols

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld-preload

I am trying to LD_PRELOAD functions such as `mmap`, `read`, `open`, `clone` etc..., but while some function do get LD_PRELOADed successfully, others don't. For example `mmap`, `read` and `open` are perfectly being preloaded but `clone` is not, while I know for sure `clone` is being called from my program as reported by `strace`, since I'm using pthreads. What is the reason for `clone` not being LD_PRELOADed here?

Comment: How did you discover `clone` is not being preloaded?  How did you determine the others are being preloaded?

Comment: I put a printf inside my LD_PRELOADed version.

Comment: Note that GCC is being (un)helpful, and as a part of its optimization processes, it changes several function calls to others (like printf()'ing with a constant string results in a puts()). So make sure your symbols are those you would epect to be!

Comment: `strace` shows system calls -- which afaik is different from a call to the C *wrapper* which you are trying to replace.  One thing you may want to check is the address of `clone()` and compare against `/proc/<pid>/maps` to see for sure which library is being used. It's possible the system call is not being made via the `clone()` wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strace` shows *system calls*; LD_PRELOAD overrides (C library) *functions*.  This probably indicates that the `clone` system call is being invoked by a different function, without going through the `clone` function symbol (e.g. through internal linkage inside the C library, or invoking the system call directly).

Indeed, `clone` is not a Posix library function; it is a Linux implementation detail that happens to be exposed.  The man page says:

> The clone() and sys_clone calls are Linux-specific and should not be used in programs intended to be portable.

Instead you should LD_PRELOAD-override `pthread_create` etc.; on other platforms they may be implemented without `clone`.

Comment: More importantly, `pthread_create` **cannot** call `clone` because `clone` is in the namespace reserved for the application.